# Convert time by moment.js and timezone

Tags: datetime, momentjs

I have a complicated problem with time converting;

I am coding by node.js and use moment, moment-jalaali and moment-timezone

I get a time from clinet in jalali format( example: `1396-03-03T23:00:00.00+04:30`) to search and find some data before or after a time which is saved on UTC; My server has -04:00 zone;

```
var moment = require('moment');
var momentJalali = require('moment-jalaali');
var momentTZ = require('moment-timezone');

var jFormat = "jYYYY-jM-jD HH:mm:ss z";
var format = "YYYY-M-D HH:mm:ss z";
var toDate = momentJalali(req.body.toDate, jFormat).tz('UTC').format(format);

console.log("date: \n" + toDate "\n " + moment().format('Z') + "\n"); //output: date:
2017-5-25 03:00:00 UTC
-04:00
```

The response I expect is `2017-5-24 19:30:00 UTC`; How could I reach that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need moment-timezone for this.  Simply parse the input in UTC mode.  Since you provided an offset, it will be taken into account automatically.

```
moment.utc("1396-03-03T23:00:00.00+04:30", "jYYYY-jMM-jDDTHH:mm:ss.SSZ")
      .format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss z")

//=>  "2017-05-24 18:30:00 UTC"
```

Also note you had a few formatting tokens wrong - they are case-sensitive.

Additionally, I would seriously consider *not* using that particular input format if you have any control over it.  By convention, it appears to be in ISO-8601 extended format, except that ISO-8601 is *strictly* bound to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.  My understanding is that Jalaali dates are typically written as `1396/3/3 23:00:00`, which would be `jYYYY/jM/jD HH:mm:ss`.

Also note that the value you asked for in your question is actually an hour off. your local time is 4.5 hours ahead of UTC so subtract: `23 - 4.5 = 18.5`, thus `18:30 UTC`, not `19:30 UTC`.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your code and also the information about date format you have provided; It helps me a lot